# Latex port to the iPad

Tags: ipad, latex

How hard could It be to have the Tex engine and consequently latex compiling documents on an iPad? Is that a fool idea? Is there something already done?

I saw a Latex app on the app store that claims to be able to typeset documents through a link to a home always on dropbox server. This is not the solution I'm thinking to. I'd like to have my iPad producing PDF (with pdflatex) onto the iPad itself.

Comment: I guess online compilers wouldn't do it for you then, right? If you are willing to consider them, check out the options given here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online

Comment: Should be on tex.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FAQ](http://www.vancapy.com/textouch/FAQ/) of the app says:

> **Q:** Why is it not possible to compile .tex code into a .pdf on the iPad?
>
> **A:** Apple wouldn't allow any kind of code compiling on the iPad and currently it is technically impossible to run an executable outside an app (like i.e. pdflatex). So it is impossible to include a LaTeX distribution into any iPad/iPhone app. I'd love to add this feature but it can't be done that way. Sorry.
> I will investigate into whether the new AppStore rules still forbid code compiling on the device.